# On click check the closest radio button within div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to style some radio buttons so that when you click the div, it selects the radio button inside the div.

At the moment, when you click the third div in the list for example, it selects the first div's input. These all have the same ID as it's been written in a razor `foreach` loop.

here is the HTML generated

```
<div id="world-container" class="d-flex">
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="CityTypeId" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="1">
      <label for="CityTypeId">Urban</label>
   </div>
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="CityTypeId" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="2">
      <label for="CityTypeId">Countryside</label>
   </div>
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="CityTypeId" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="3">
      <label for="CityTypeId">Coastal</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery I'm trying to use to select the closest radio button inside that div

```
$(".button-styles").on("click", function () {

    $(this).children('#CityTypeId').prop('checked', true);
    
});
```

I can't change the way this HTML is written due to the `MVC foreach` loop.

Any suggestions or advice how to get around this would be great.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `for` from label.
Remove `id` from input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An id should be unique throw a document , you did semantic error by duplicating `ids` ,

for your issue use classes instead : ( you've already predifined class )

```
$(this).find('input.city-type-radio').prop('checked', true);
```

See snippet below :

```js
$(".button-styles").on("click", function () {

    $(this).find('input.city-type-radio').prop('checked', true);
    
});
```

```css
.image-item {
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="world-container" class="d-flex">
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="cityTypeId1" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="1">
      <label for="cityTypeId1">Urban</label>
   </div>
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="cityTypeId2" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="2">
      <label for="cityTypeId2">Countryside</label>
   </div>
   <div class="button-styles image-item">
      <input class="city-type-radio" id="cityTypeId3" name="CityTypeId" type="radio" value="3">
      <label for="cityTypeId3">Coastal</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

ID has to be unique, that's the reason why your code don't work. Try to target `input` directly.

```
$(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);
```